# remove table row with specific id

Tags: jquery

I have the following table:

```
<table id="test">
 <tr id=1><td>bla</td></tr>
 <tr id=2><td>bla</td></tr>
 <tr id=3><td>bla</td></tr>
 <tr id=4><td>bla</td></tr>
</table>
```

Now I want to remove row 3 from the table. How do I do that?
Something like:

```
$("#test tr ??").remove();
```

Thanks!

Comment: ID's are not supposed to start with numbers.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Try

```
$('table#test tr#3').remove();
```

Comment: As other answers have stated your ID is also possibly invalid.

Comment: What if I give common class in place of ID's, in case of dynamic data ?

Comment: @PonnaveenS I'm not sure I follow, this particular question was asking how to remove a row with a specific id attribute. I provided the answer as above which stated how to do this. If you're asking another question please post to stackoverflow as a new question and we can deal with it that way.

Answer (score 17):

ID attributes cannot start with a number and they should be unique.  In any case, you can use [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to select a specific row using a 0-based integer:

```
// Remove the third row
$("#test tr:eq(2)").remove();
```

Alternatively, rewrite your HTML so that it's valid:

```
<table id="test">
 <tr id=test1><td>bla</td></tr>
 <tr id=test2><td>bla</td></tr>
 <tr id=test3><td>bla</td></tr>
 <tr id=test4><td>bla</td></tr>
</table>
```

And remove it referencing just the id:

```
$("#test3").remove();
```

Answer (score 7):

Remove by id -

`$("#3").remove();`

Also I would suggest to use better naming, like row-1, row-2

Answer (score 6):

Simply `$("#3").remove();` would be enough. But `3` isn't a good id (I think it's even illegal, as it starts with a digit).

Answer (score 5):

```
$('#3').remove();
```

http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#3').remove();
```

Might not work with numeric id's though.

Answer (score 2):

> As bellow we can remove table rows with specific row id

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function remove(id)
{
$('table#test tr#'+id).remove();
// or you can use bellow line also
//$('#test tr#'+id).remove();
}
</script>
    </head>
<body>
<table id="test">
 <tr id="1"><td>bla</td><td><input type="button" onclick="remove(1)"value="Remove"></td></tr>
 <tr id="2"><td>bla</td><td><input type="button" onclick="remove(2)" value="Remove"></td></tr>
 <tr id="3"><td>bla</td><td><input type="button" onclick="remove(3)" value="Remove"></td></tr>
 <tr id="4"><td>bla</td><td><input type="button" onclick="remove(4)" value="Remove"></td></tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

Comment: PLease edit your answer to explain why and how this addresses the original question.

Comment: As above we can remove table rows with specific row id.

Comment: Please *edit your answer* to include the explanation, as many people don't read the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$("#test tr:eq(2)").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [:eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector:

```
$("#test tr:eq(2)").remove();
```